# How do I convert a struct_time output into DD/MM/YY, Hour:Minute:Second format?

Tags: python, time, sensors

I'm relatively uninitiated when it comes to Python, and I'm trying to figure out how to take an output I'm getting from a sensor into proper day, month, year and hour, minute, second format.

An example of the output, which also includes a basic counter (the first output), and a timestamp (the third output) is shown below:

```
(305, struct_time(tm_year=2022, tm_mon=11, tm_mday=9, tm_hour=16, tm_min=42, tm_sec=8, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=313, tm_isdst=-1), 7.036)
```

I've seen a lot of questions and answers for this, but I'm left feeling kind of stumped on all of them because I'm not sure how to take the output I have (real_time, which gives a struct_time output) and turn it into this format. Any help (and understanding about my lack of fluency in this field) would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

[`time.strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strftime) exists for exactly this purpose:

```py
import time

now_local = time.localtime()

fmt = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"
out = time.strftime(fmt, now_local)

print(out)
```

However, two words of warning:

1. `time.struct_time` is *not* "timezone aware". This will turn out to matter when you least expect it. Unless you are very sure that you know the timezone of the incoming data, and have the correct safeguards in your application and database for managing time zone iformation, use the `datetime.datetime` class instead.
2. `D/M/Y` date format can be ambiguous. `Y-M-D` format is substantially safer. It is not ambiguous in any widely-used locale, and it has the extra benefit that lexical ordering of `Y-M-D` strings is also a correct ordering of the dates that they represent. This format is laid out by [RFC 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339) and has become widely accepted as the standard, correct formatting for datetime strings.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! You made your answer as elegant and easy to understand as possible and I'm in your debt for that. I feel like I'm definitely on the right track now, HOWEVER, I'm now getting this error message:

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'strftime' import time

I'm wondering if this might be because I'm running CircuitPython instead of one of the "normal" versions.

Comment: (Also, apologies, I can't figure out how to indent my text on this site)

Comment: @snbelair unfortunately that appears to be the case: https://docs.circuitpython.org/en/latest/shared-bindings/time/. If you figure out a nice way to do this with CircuitPython specifically, feel free to post it as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 1):

So as it turns out, I was able to find a solution after all. Essentially I just used this function:

```
    def _format_datetime(datetime):
        return "{:02}/{:02}/{} {:02}:{:02}:{:02}".format(
            datetime.tm_mon,
            datetime.tm_mday,
            datetime.tm_year,
            datetime.tm_hour,
            datetime.tm_min,
            datetime.tm_sec,
            )
```

And then applied it to the struct_time output as such (with real_time being said output):

```
        real_time = time.localtime()
        current_time = time.monotonic()

        formatted_time = _format_datetime(real_time)
```

Hopefully this helps other people using CircuitPython for similar purposes!